# Ruby XMLRPC pass keypair

Tags: ruby, xml-rpc

I have to interact with an XML-RPC server that uses key authentication.  Before accepting the request, the server verifies the key pair (ssl private key and ssl cert).  I understand this is terrible, but it's what I have to work with.

My question is this: is there an easy way to pass the key and certificate in this request?  I am using the xmlrpc/Client in Ruby, but the documentation does not seem to indicate this can be done.  My current code is as follows:

Error:

> /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in `connect': sslv3 alert handshake failure >(OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
>          from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:586:in`connect'
>          from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
>          from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in`start'
>          from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request'
>          from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:992:in`post2'
>          from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmlrpc/client.rb:535:in `do_rpc'
>          from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmlrpc/client.rb:420:in`call2'
>          from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/xmlrpc/client.rb:410:in `call'

Class File:

```
class RpcRequest

  require "xmlrpc/client"

  # Automatically create the connection
  def initialize(connection_params)
    @connection = XMLRPC::Client.new(connection_params['host'], connection_params['path'], connection_params['port'], connection_params['proxy_host'], connection_params['proxy_port'], connection_params['user'], connection_params['password'], connection_params['use_ssl'], connection_params['timeout'])
  end

  # Make the xml rpc call
    def make_call(method, request_params)
      @response = @connection.call(method, request_params)
    end

end
```

Driver file:

```
require 'RpcRequest.rb'
require 'config.rb'
require 'openssl'

# Define parameters for the connection
connect_params = Hash.new
connect_params['host'] = $host
connect_params['path'] = $path
connect_params['port'] = $port
connect_params['proxy_host'] = $proxy_host
connect_params['proxy_port'] = $proxy_port
connect_params['user'] = $user
connect_params['password'] = $password
connect_params['use_ssl'] = $use_ssl
connect_params['timeout'] = $timeout

# Define parameters for the request
request_params = Hash.new
request_params['fname'] = 'Robert'
request_params['lname'] = 'Jones'

request = RpcRequest.new(connect_params)

puts request.inspect

request.make_call('test.hello', request_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can interact with the .http property of the client instance.